# Variance of squared random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, expectation

Can anyone help to prove this equation for any distribution
$$
E(z^4)=1+\operatorname{Var}(z^2)
$$
where $z$ is a random variable with the standard normal distribution

$$z=\frac{x−μ}σ$$

Comment: Take the special case where $z$ is a constant. Do you think the formula is correct?

Comment: z is not a constant. I have already asked in mathoverflow and suggested to ask here

Comment: z constant is a particular case of a random variable. If your formula were correct for any random variable, then it would be correct for constant $z$. It's not, hence your formula is wrong.

Comment: Maybe $z$ was supposed to be of standard normal distribution. Then then equation holds and you have a proof below.

Comment: It was my fault that didn't mention that $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ !
So $z$ is following the standard normal distribution and hence $E(z^2)=1$. Am I right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we have is 
$$\operatorname{Var}\left(z^2\right)=\mathbb E\left[\left(z^2\right)^2\right]-\left(\mathbb E\left[z^2\right]\right)^2=\mathbb E\left[z^4\right]-\left(\mathbb E\left[z^2\right]\right)^2,$$
so the formula in the opening post is true if and only if $\mathbb E\left[z^2\right]=1$.